# Removing Duplicated data entirely without maintaining one

Tags: python

I found that there are several ways of removing duplicated data.
However, for obvious reasons none of them (at least what I've found) removes the duplicates entirely but rather maintains a single unique data point.
However, I concluded for my model that this results in some erroneous behavior and was wondering if there is any way that I can remove all candidates of the duplicates.
To be more clear, if the data is as below for instance:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [5, 2, 1, 4],
     [5, 2, 1, 4],
     [3, 4, 2, 4]]
```

Then I want nothing but the last row [3, 4, 2, 4] where duplicates are removed entirely (I'm struggling to find the right expression).
I've tried using 'for' loop (by extracting the data that was not unique and comparing them each to the unique data set then removing them as well), however, my data is about 50k and this takes too much time. Is there an efficient way to do this in python?

P.S. just in case, I used the code below to find the unique set of data points

```
temp = np.ascontiguousarray(raw_input).view(np.dtype((np.void, raw_input.dtype.itemsize*raw_input.shape[1])))
_, idx = np.unique(temp, return_index = True)
input_data = raw_input[idx] # unique input data
output_data = output_label[idx]
```

Comment: Would creating a second array with only the unique elements be acceptable for you?

Comment: Given a list of 50000 4-tuples, building a `Counter` takes about 3ms, and collecting all the rows with count 1 takes at worst 5ms if there are no dups, and a lot less if there are many dups. So by "too much time", are you talking about single-digit milliseconds, or is your code vastly less efficient than this obvious two-liner?

Comment: If you need to retain order, you need an OrderedCounter recipe (or an OrderedDict plus some extra code), but we're still talking around 30ms instead of 8, which doesn't seem way too slow to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Staying within "standard" Python,

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(map(tuple, x))
output_data = [list(k) for k, v in c.items() if v == 1]
```

If you want to know the indices (in `x`) of rows that were removed (because they had duplicates), you can do the following:

```
rem = [idx for idx, k in enumerate(x) if c[tuple(k)] > 1]
```

---

Alternatively (or preferably) using `numpy`:

```
u, invidx, cnt = np.unique(x, axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
rem = np.flatnonzero(cnt[invidx] > 1)
output_data = u[cnt == 1]
```

---

#### Example:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: x = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
   ...:      [1, 2, 3, 4],
   ...:      [5, 2, 1, 4],
   ...:      [5, 2, 1, 4],
   ...:      [3, 4, 2, 4]]
   ...:      

In [3]: c = Counter(map(tuple, x))

In [4]: output_data = [list(k) for k, v in c.items() if v == 1]

In [5]: print(output_data)
[[3, 4, 2, 4]]
```

#### Example using `numpy`:

```
In [30]: u, invidx, cnt = np.unique(x, axis=0, return_inverse=True,
    ...: return_counts=True)

In [31]: print(u)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [3 4 2 4]
 [5 2 1 4]]

In [32]: print(invidx)
[0 0 2 2 1]

In [33]: print(cnt)
[2 1 2]

In [34]: rem = np.flatnonzero(cnt[invidx] > 1)

In [35]: output_data = u[cnt == 1]

In [36]: print(rem)
[0 1 2 3]

In [37]: print(output_data)
[[3 4 2 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is sort of what I wanted. However, I realized that I have asked this question without much detail. Currently, I have data in a form of Numpy array. However, converting to list or vice versa doesn't take too much time so I guess this isn't a huge issue. What I am trying to do is to remove all data with more than two occurrences. This can be done with the answer that you have given me, however, I cannot connect the data that has been removed with the output labels. Hence, I need the index for the removed data or at least some way to achieve the label connection.

Comment: Would there be a way to remove rows of data depending on the input data (what you have done currently) and remove the output label along with it?

Comment: @CodyChung Let me think.. I'll post back when I have a solution in `numpy`. With regard to indices, it is easy to modify current solution to keep track of removed indices (I think).

Comment: @CodyChung I just added second example that shows how to get the indices of removed rows from `x`.

Comment: `final_list = list(filter(lambda tup:x.count(tup)==1,x))`

Comment: @CodyChung I just added also a solution using `numpy`

Comment: @CodyChung You are welcome. I kind of also like my `numpy` solution... I wasn't expecting it to be this simple.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
final_list = list(filter(lambda tup:x.count(list(tup))==1, list(set(map(tuple,x)))))
list(map(list,final_list))
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, and I am not going to downwote it, but I do not like this solution because it is _very_ inefficient: for every row (`tup`) you ask array `x` to count how many times that line repeats. Now you made this a quadratic time problem.

Comment: `final_list = list(filter(lambda tup:x.count(list(tup))==1, list(set(map(tuple,x)))))`
`list(map(list,final_list))`
for best case complexity

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?:

```
a=[[1,2],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[3,4]]
b=a[:]
for i in range(len(a)-1,0,-1):
    if a[i] == a[i-1]:
        del b[i-1:i+1]

# a == [[1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 4]]
# b == [[2, 3]]
```